# Laravel 5.1 - Routes are correct and on localhost works perfectly, online gives me 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've just configured my routes correctly as i do usually:

```
Route::get('/news/', 'PagesController@news');
Route::get('/news/{id}', 'PagesController@newsDetail');
```

In my PagesController i create also 2 variables to pass to the view:

```
$relatedOlder = (
    News::where('created_at', '<', $currentPostDate)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->value('created_at') != '') ? 
    News::where('created_at', '<', $currentPostDate)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->firstOrFail() : 
    News::where('created_at', '>', $currentPostDate)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->skip(1)->take(2)->firstOrFail();

$relatedNewer = (
    News::where('created_at', '>', $currentPostDate)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->value('created_at') != '') ? 
    News::where('created_at', '>', $currentPostDate)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->firstOrFail() : 
    News::where('created_at', '<', $currentPostDate)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(2)->firstOrFail();
```

On localhost everything works perfectly, but online these 2 variables give me `404 error` once i go to `/news/{id-of-my-post}` If i don't pass to my view these vars it works. My query seems to be correct but i don't understand if it could be a server/cache problem or what else.
Any idea?

Comment: Does that model->id exist in the online DB? Did you forget to seed, for example?

Comment: My db online is the same, i've checked it more than once. On my server online i don't have permission to access from terminal and use php artisan, but i've exported from my localhost phpmyadmin.

Comment: Is it that you don't have mod_rewrite enabled (or the host doesn't allow .htaccess overrides)? Is the 404 page a Laravel style 404 or a general web server 404?

Comment: the error is a Laravel 404 style, i'm on GoDaddy service

Comment: I think i've find something: in my method `update()` from my `NewsController` i see that when i call `update()` and i modify my `updated_at` field, my `created_at` field changes too. but i don't have any instruction to do that, i have only `$update['updated_at'] = Carbon::now();`. Here's my function: `public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        //
        $post = News::findOrFail($id);
        $update = $request->only('date', 'title', 'cont');
        $update['updated_at'] = Carbon::now();
        $post->update($update);
        return redirect('admin/news');
    }`

Comment: You should really change those variables to not use `firstOrFail()` - it's quite possible that a given item won't have a relatedOlder or relatedNewer (what if it's the first or last or only item, right?) At a guess the disparity between local and online is that your database content is different. Just change the `firstOrFail()`s to `first()`s and do the appropriate checking in your view to show/not show some links or whatever these variables are for.

Comment: You're my hero, it works. I still have to understund why on update() my "created_at" field changes too. This causes errors for my dates. Maybe i have to find a method to exclude this on update

Comment: you need to chage the order of routes declaration, `/news/` should be placed after `/news/{id}`